# Bluetooth LE with AES encryption data size

Tags: bluetooth, aes, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question about Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) and AES encryption data size. BLE uses AES. AES block size is 16byte. If data is less than 16byte, we need to add padding. But when I sniff BLE data by Nordic sniffer, it shows payload size is 5 byte or 7 byte. I do not know how to decrypt less than 16 byte with AES.

In most of case, BLE MTU size is 20byte. But AES block size is 16byte. How to handle 17byte data? After AES encryption, it become 32byte and over MTU size.

Comment: I have no idea about BLE, but it's entirely possible that AES is used in a streaming mode like CTR, but then the question is how the nonce is set.

Comment: By your response, I have a idea of streaming mode. BLE uses CCM mode, and CCM is a derivation of CTR mode. So BLE do not have to send whole 16 byte block.